# How to fix syntax error near 'ORDER BY DESC'?

Tags: mysql

I'm running MYSQL version 5.5 and I am receiving the following errors. I have tried adding `LIMIT 1` to the end, removing `ORDER BY DESC` specifying to sort by `DATE(submit_date)`... yet still I receive the same error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY DESC' at line 1

```
SELECT status, DATE(submit_date) FROM ". $GLOBALS['TABLES']['APPLICATION'] ." WHERE fk_userid = $userId ORDER BY DESC
```

Comment: You need to `ORDER BY` _something_.  That being said, which column or alias do you want to use for ordering?

Comment: `order by date(subit_date) desc`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen submit date. But as mentioned I tried adding DATE(submit_date) yet I still get the error.  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY DATE(submit_date) DESC' at line 1

Comment: @acctman Please show us the actual query string which is being passed to MySQL.  This is critical for us to answer your question.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a field in your order by clause : `ORDER BY DESC`

Either add a field: `ORDER BY someField DESC` or remove the `ORDER BY DESC` text.

Comment: i've tried both, prior to posting... this is the error with ORDER BY DESC removed. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: @acctman add a semi-colon (;) inside the quotes after the userId?

Comment: this is my code line `$SQLString = "SELECT status FROM ". $GLOBALS['TABLES']['APPLICATION'] ." WHERE fk_userid = $userId";` and i'm getting the error i posted above

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the column_name.

**SQL ORDER BY Syntax:**

```
SELECT column_name, column_name
 FROM table_name
 ORDER BY column_name ASC|DESC, column_name ASC|DESC;
```

from: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp